# What is the cartesian product of two relations with a common attribute

Tags: relation-algebra

### What I know about the Cartesian Product

I just learned about the cartesian  product in my introduction to Databases. The example that was provided was pretty clear. For a relation A with *n* tuples and relation B with *m* tuples, I need to create a relation C that will have n*m tuples. Every tuple i from A will create m new tuples, for each tuple from B,  in the Relation C.

[Example of a Cartesian Product in the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciBAv.jpg)

### Actual Question:

In the next example I learned how to make natural join from two relations that share a common attribute and have common values for that common attribute.

I was wondering how - if even possible - I could take the cartesian product from that example.

*See picture two from the first link.*

### What I have tried:

[My attempt at making the cartesian product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u5R4.png)

[Edit:] 
In this attempt I created a new table. The **blue bits** are the tuples that contain the values from the A/B table that I got from the example in the natural join. The **red bits** are the tuples that I got from the B/D relation from the natural join example. I was wondering  if I was allowed to combine them in such a way to make the cartesian product easier to see.

The table of the example of the natural join is in the second image in the first link.

I have tried searching my question online, I'm sure someone must have answered it somewhere already. However I couldn't define my problem well enough. What could I have modified to my query to have gotten to the result?

Thanks

*PS: I don't have 10 reputation points yet, So I can't embed images in my text yet and I can't have more than two links.*

Comment: Everything in black is okay, but I have no idea what the bits in red and blue are attempting.

Comment: I tried to find the solution to my own question. In this attempt I created a new table. The blue bits are the tuples that contain the values from the A/B table that I got from the example in the natural join. The red bits are the tuples that I got from the B/D relation from the natural join example. I was wondering  if I was allowed to combine them in such a way to make the cartesian product easier to see.

Comment: I don't see *how* you obtained those rows from that example, or why you would try to concatenate tables like so.